# Why am getting authentication error for connecting to wifi via wifi adapter with correct password?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-driver, centos-8

```
(base) [msingh@centos rtl8192eu-linux-driver]$ sudo nmcli --ask dev wifi connect ACT103292835565
Password: ••••••••••••
Error: Connection activation failed:(53) The Wi-Fi network could not be found

(base) [msingh@centos ~]$ journalctl -fu wpa_supplicant
-- Logs begin at Tue 2020-08-25 21:49:01 IST. --
Aug 25 21:49:20 centos.example.com systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
Aug 25 21:49:20 centos.example.com systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
Aug 25 21:49:20 centos.example.com wpa_supplicant[2860]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Aug 25 23:48:08 centos.example.com wpa_supplicant[2860]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface.P2PDevice dbus_property=P2PDeviceConfig getter failed
Aug 25 23:48:08 centos.example.com wpa_supplicant[2860]: wlp41s0f3u2u4: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Aug 25 23:53:12 centos.example.com wpa_supplicant[2860]: wlp41s0f3u2u4: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Aug 25 23:58:14 centos.example.com wpa_supplicant[2860]: wlp41s0f3u2u4: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Aug 25 23:59:09 centos.example.com wpa_supplicant[2860]: wlp41s0f3u2u4: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:ad:24:f6:6a:d9 (SSID='ACT103292835565' freq=2437 MHz)
Aug 25 23:59:11 centos.example.com wpa_supplicant[2860]: wlp41s0f3u2u4: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:ad:24:f6:6a:d9 (SSID='ACT103292835565' freq=2437 MHz)
Aug 25 23:59:14 centos.example.com wpa_supplicant[2860]: wlp41s0f3u2u4: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:ad:24:f6:6a:d9 (SSID='ACT103292835565' freq=2437 MHz)
Aug 25 23:59:17 centos.example.com wpa_supplicant[2860]: wlp41s0f3u2u4: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:ad:24:f6:6a:d9 (SSID='ACT103292835565' freq=2437 MHz)
Aug 25 23:59:18 centos.example.com wpa_supplicant[2860]: wlp41s0f3u2u4: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="ACT103292835565" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
```

What do these errors mean, Is there any way to troubleshoot this?

EDIT:

```
(base) [msingh@centos ~]$ nmcli d wifi list
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID             MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        00:AD:24:F6:6A:D9  ACT103292835565  Infra  6     270 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆    WPA1 WPA2

(base) [msingh@centos ~]$ lsmod | grep rtl
rtl8xxxu              126976  0
mac80211              888832  1 rtl8xxxu
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             634880  31 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
(base) [msingh@centos ~]$ lsusb | grep TP
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2357:0109 TP-Link TL WN823N RTL8192EU
(base) [msingh@centos ~]$
```

Last few lines of `dmesg | grep wlp41s0f3u2u4`

```
[Wed Aug 26 00:31:03 2020] wlp41s0f3u2u4: authenticate with 00:ad:24:f6:6a:d9
[Wed Aug 26 00:31:03 2020] wlp41s0f3u2u4: send auth to 00:ad:24:f6:6a:d9 (try 1/3)
[Wed Aug 26 00:31:03 2020] wlp41s0f3u2u4: send auth to 00:ad:24:f6:6a:d9 (try 2/3)
[Wed Aug 26 00:31:03 2020] wlp41s0f3u2u4: send auth to 00:ad:24:f6:6a:d9 (try 3/3)
[Wed Aug 26 00:31:03 2020] wlp41s0f3u2u4: authentication with 00:ad:24:f6:6a:d9 timed out
[Wed Aug 26 00:31:17 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp41s0f3u2u4: link is not ready
[Wed Aug 26 00:31:17 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp41s0f3u2u4: link is not ready
[Wed Aug 26 00:36:20 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp41s0f3u2u4: link is not ready
[Wed Aug 26 00:41:20 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp41s0f3u2u4: link is not ready
[Wed Aug 26 00:46:21 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp41s0f3u2u4: link is not ready
[Wed Aug 26 00:51:23 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp41s0f3u2u4: link is not ready
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure of the network name, ACT103292835565 ? 2. Is the Wi-Fi adapter able to access the router (e.g. correct band, strong enough signal...)?

Comment: Yes i am sure, I have added more info with the edit. I have also tried with the graphical interface and it does not work. but i am able to connect to the wifi using any other device.

Comment: If this is not related to password then i think it would have to do with authentication related to certificates, it just a guess. I am not sure about that the kernel module in use is  rtl8xxxu